# The science of the book Eon by Greg Bear

Tags: novel, science-fiction-genre, greg-bear

Piggybacking on this question: Book about time portals inside an asteroid in Earth orbit.

The answer to that question was Eon by Greg Bear. In that novel an asteroid comes into orbit around Earth. When people travel to it they find that it is much bigger inside than outside. There's a tunnel that stretches on seemingly forever.

Does anyone remember how the author explained the science of how such a thing could exist? Did he go into how the tunnel could go on and on like that?

I read the book many years ago and I have to admit I didn't get it.

Comment: It was hand-waved as being advanced tech. Something to do with wormholes and nonsense about alternate dimensions. There's no hard science here, just techobabble

Comment: @Valorum Arrrgh. Thanks.

Comment: Further hand-waving consisted of pi varying. At one stage one of the characters pulls out a pi-meter and announces that it's a "bit high".

Answer (score 7):

It is 100%-pure pseudo-science, but Bear does a careful job of making it pseudo-science which doesn't contradict what we know. (Too much.)  (For example, there is no FTL-travel through ordinary space.)

General Relativity tells us that spacetime is an active thing which interacts with the rest of the universe and changes through those interactions, not a passive background or a sort of theater in which things happen. It also makes it clear that spacetime need not be topologically simple like the Euclidean space of Newtonian physics. It can be very, very complicated and twisted and interconnected and still be a perfectly good spacetime obeying General Relativity.

This all naturally leads to the possibility that a sufficiently advanced technology might be able to manipulate spacetime like we manipulate steel, and that's what we see in *Eon* and its sequels.

Bear's pseudo-science also obeys Clarke's Law and for our purposes might as well be magic. While we can't say that the twisted spacetimes of *Eon* are impossible, we can't say anything meaningful about how to bring them about, either, (other than that it would take a really, really, really *lot* of energy.)

The part that struck me as most unrealistic is that these contorted bits of spacetime don't produce extreme gravitational effects in their vicinity. GR suggests that the curvatures that appear to be present in *Eon* would manifest as really, really, really extreme gravitational fields.

But SF usually needs some sort of escape from science-as-we-know-it, and a novel that involves super-science even moreso. I think Bear did a fine job of writing realistically about very unrealistic science!

Comment: Thanks, It helps to know that even renowned authors use the handwavium too.

Comment: @Len The greats are great, in part, because they use it so very well.

Comment: Indeed, there are stage magicians who wave their hands all over the place to distract you from the card they've hidden up their sleeve, then there's the magician who hides the card up your sleeve so skillfully you'd swear they didn't move their hand at all. Bear's is the second kind of handwavium :)